# Align search module: Joomla responsive website

Tags: css, joomla, module, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been trying since yesterday to align my search module on a Joomla!'s Website to make it responsive on mobile devices, yet it's not working the way I want it to do. All I want to do it align this module to the center of the screen. This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="header-search pull-right">
    <div class="search">
        <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/aidet/">

    <label class="element-invisible" for="mod-search-searchword"></label>
    <input id="mod-search-searchword" class="inputbox search-query" type="search" placeholder=" " size="5" maxlength="200" name="searchword"></input>
    <input class="button" type="image" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();" src="/aidet/templates/protostar/images/searchButton.gif" alt="Buscar"></input>

            <input type="hidden" value="search" name="task"></input>
            <input type="hidden" value="com_search" name="option"></input>
            <input type="hidden" value="111" name="Itemid"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

While this is the media-query I'm using at the moment:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {

    .header-search .search-query {
        width: 60%;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }

    .input[type="image"] {
        width: 5px;
    }
}
```

I tried with text-align as some people suggested, and also margin: 0 auto; , but it didn't change anything. Aditionally, I'd like to resize the image at the right of the search module too, since it's pretty big on a small screen.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` will only work if the element is a `block` element and has a set width in pixels, not a percentage, so try the following:

```
.header-search .search-query {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. However, the image search button on the right of the search-box is now below it, while I forgot to say that I need it to be at the same line. I tried changing display: block to inline-block, but then it ignores the margin as you commented.

Comment: In this case, I would wrap 2  elements you want on the same line in a parent element and apply the CSS in my answer to that parent element instead

Comment: It's not working yet. I tried adding your code on .header-search, yet the image is still below the search-box. However, I've noticed on the CSS these styles for the image:
.form-inline input{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input, textarea, .uneditable-input {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

I tried changing .form-inline input to display: block as well, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle or provide a link to your site?

Comment: This is way too complex. Only need the search section and CSS that being used for it currently. Not the whole file.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. https://jsfiddle.net/o9xat53x/1/ These should be the CSS lines used by the seach box module.

Comment: I don't know what happened because I didn't change anything at all since that day, but it's now working.. It's such a mystery. Thank you very much for your help, Lodder.